# SQL high CPU usage (SharePoint query)

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

Since two weeks the CPU usage of SQL Server is regularly very high (99%).

In SSMS activity monitor I have got the following SQL query:

```
SELECT ScopeId, Acl, AnonymousPermMask
FROM Perms WITH (INDEX=Perms_Url)
WHERE SiteId=@SITEID AND DelTransId = 0x AND ScopeId IN (SELECT tp_ScopeId FROM TVF_Lists_NoLock_CI(@SITEID, @L12, @L2)  UNION SELECT t1.ScopeId FROM AllUserData AS UserData INNER JOIN Docs AS t1 WITH(NOLOCK) ON (UserData.[tp_ID]=t1.[DoclibRowId]) AND (UserData.[tp_RowOrdinal] = 0) AND (t1.SiteId=UserData.tp_SiteId) AND (t1.SiteId = @SITEID) AND (t1.ParentId = UserData.tp_ParentId) AND (t1.Id = UserData.tp_DocId) AND (UserData.tp_ListId = @L2 AND UserData.tp_SiteId = @SITEID) AND (UserData.[tp_IsCurrentVersion] = CONVERT(bit,1) ) AND (UserData.[tp_CalculatedVersion] = 0 ) AND (UserData.[tp_DeleteTransactionId] = 0x ) LEFT OUTER LOOP JOIN AllUserData AS t2 WITH(FORCESEEK(AllUserData_PK(tp_SiteId,tp_ListId,tp_DeleteTransactionId,tp_IsCurrentVersion,tp_ID,tp_CalculatedVersion)),NOLOCK) ON (UserData.[tp_CheckoutUserId]=t2.[tp_ID]) AND (UserData.[tp_RowOrdinal] = 0) AND (t2.[tp_RowOrdinal] = 0) AND ( (t2.tp_Level = 1) ) AND (t2.[tp_IsCurrentVersion] = CONVERT(bit,1) ) AND (t2.[tp_CalculatedVersion] = 0 ) AND (t2.[tp_DeleteTransactionId] = 0x ) AND (t2.tp_ListId = @L3 AND t2.tp_SiteId = @SITEID) AND (UserData.tp_ListId = @L2 AND UserData.tp_SiteId = @SITEID) AND (UserData.[tp_IsCurrentVersion] = CONVERT(bit,1) ) AND (UserData.[tp_CalculatedVersion] = 0 ) AND (UserData.[tp_DeleteTransactionId] = 0x ) LEFT OUTER LOOP JOIN AllUserData AS t3 WITH(FORCESEEK(AllUserData_PK(tp_SiteId,tp_ListId,tp_DeleteTransactionId,tp_IsCurrentVersion,tp_ID,tp_CalculatedVersion)),NOLOCK) ON (UserData.[tp_Editor]=t3.[tp_ID]) AND (UserData.[tp_RowOrdinal] = 0) AND (t3.[tp_RowOrdinal] = 0) AND ( (t3.tp_Level = 1) ) AND (t3.[tp_IsCurrentVersion] = CONVERT(bit,1) ) AND (t3.[tp_CalculatedVersion] = 0 ) AND (t3.[tp_DeleteTransactionId] = 0x ) AND (t3.tp_ListId = @L3 AND t3.tp_SiteId = @SITEID) AND (UserData.tp_ListId = @L2 AND UserData.tp_SiteId = @SITEID) AND (UserData.[tp_IsCurrentVersion] = CONVERT(bit,1) ) AND (UserData.[tp_CalculatedVersion] = 0 ) AND (UserData.[tp_DeleteTransactionId] = 0x ) LEFT OUTER LOOP JOIN AllUserData AS t4 WITH(FORCESEEK(AllUserData_PK(tp_SiteId,tp_ListId,tp_DeleteTransactionId,tp_IsCurrentVersion,tp_ID,tp_CalculatedVersion)),NOLOCK) ON (UserData.[int12]=t4.[tp_ID]) AND (UserData.[tp_RowOrdinal] = 0) AND (t4.[tp_RowOrdinal] = 0) AND ( (t4.tp_Level = 1) ) AND (t4.[tp_IsCurrentVersion] = CONVERT(bit,1) ) AND (t4.[tp_CalculatedVersion] = 0 ) AND (t4.[tp_DeleteTransactionId] = 0x ) AND (t4.tp_ListId = @L4 AND t4.tp_SiteId = @SITEID) AND (UserData.tp_ListId = @L2 AND UserData.tp_SiteId = @SITEID) AND (UserData.[tp_IsCurrentVersion] = CONVERT(bit,1) ) AND (UserData.[tp_CalculatedVersion] = 0 ) AND (UserData.[tp_DeleteTransactionId] = 0x ) LEFT OUTER LOOP JOIN AllUserData AS t5 WITH(FORCESEEK(AllUserData_PK(tp_SiteId,tp_ListId,tp_DeleteTransactionId,tp_IsCurrentVersion,tp_ID,tp_CalculatedVersion)),NOLOCK) ON (UserData.[int13]=t5.[tp_ID]) AND (UserData.[tp_RowOrdinal] = 0) AND (t5.[tp_RowOrdinal] = 0) AND ( (t5.tp_Level = 1) ) AND (t5.[tp_IsCurrentVersion] = CONVERT(bit,1) ) AND (t5.[tp_CalculatedVersion] = 0 ) AND (t5.[tp_DeleteTransactionId] = 0x ) AND (t5.tp_ListId = @L5 AND t5.tp_SiteId = @SITEID) AND (UserData.tp_ListId = @L2 AND UserData.tp_SiteId = @SITEID) AND (UserData.[tp_IsCurrentVersion] = CONVERT(bit,1) ) AND (UserData.[tp_CalculatedVersion] = 0 ) AND (UserData.[tp_DeleteTransactionId] = 0x ) LEFT OUTER LOOP JOIN AllUserData AS t6 WITH(FORCESEEK(AllUserData_PK(tp_SiteId,tp_ListId,tp_DeleteTransactionId,tp_IsCurrentVersion,tp_ID,tp_CalculatedVersion)),NOLOCK) ON (UserData.[int15]=t6.[tp_ID]) AND (UserData.[tp_RowOrdinal] = 0) AND (t6.[tp_RowOrdinal] = 0) AND ( (t6.tp_Level = 1) ) AND (t6.[tp_IsCurrentVersion] = CONVERT(bit,1) ) AND (t6.[tp_CalculatedVersion] = 0 ) AND (t6.[tp_DeleteTransactionId] = 0x ) AND (t6.tp_ListId = @L6 AND t6.tp_SiteId = @SITEID) AND (UserData.tp_ListId = @L2 AND UserData.tp_SiteId = @SITEID) AND (UserData.[tp_IsCurrentVersion] = CONVERT(bit,1) ) AND (UserData.[tp_CalculatedVersion] = 0 ) AND (UserData.[tp_DeleteTransactionId] = 0x ) LEFT OUTER LOOP JOIN AllUserData AS t7 WITH(FORCESEEK(AllUserData_PK(tp_SiteId,tp_ListId,tp_DeleteTransactionId,tp_IsCurrentVersion,tp_ID,tp_CalculatedVersion)),NOLOCK) ON (UserData.[int14]=t7.[tp_ID]) AND (UserData.[tp_RowOrdinal] = 0) AND (t7.[tp_RowOrdinal] = 0) AND ( (t7.tp_Level = 1) ) AND (t7.[tp_IsCurrentVersion] = CONVERT(bit,1) ) AND (t7.[tp_CalculatedVersion] = 0 ) AND (t7.[tp_DeleteTransactionId] = 0x ) AND (t7.tp_ListId = @L7 AND t7.tp_SiteId = @SITEID) AND (UserData.tp_ListId = @L2 AND UserData.tp_SiteId = @SITEID) AND (UserData.[tp_IsCurrentVersion] = CONVERT(bit,1) ) AND (UserData.[tp_CalculatedVersion] = 0 ) AND (UserData.[tp_DeleteTransactionId] = 0x ) WHERE ( (UserData.tp_Level = 1 OR UserData.tp_Level =  2 OR  UserData.tp_Level =255)  AND ( UserData.tp_Level= 255 AND UserData.tp_CheckoutUserId = @IU OR  ( UserData.tp_Level  = 2 AND UserData.tp_DraftOwnerId IS NOT NULL OR UserData.tp_Level  = 1 AND UserData.tp_DraftOwnerId IS  NULL  ) AND ( UserData.tp_CheckoutUserId IS  NULL  OR UserData.tp_CheckoutUserId <> @IU))) AND (UserData.tp_SiteId=@SITEID AND (UserData.tp_ParentId=@DocParentIdForRF)) AND (UserData.tp_RowOrdinal=0) AND ((UserData.[ntext6] LIKE N'') AND t1.SiteId=@SITEID AND (t1.ParentId=@DocParentIdForRF))) OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

I do not know where it comes from. I think this query is generated by SharePoint.

This is a SharePoint 2016 farm.

Do you have any ideas to improve performance / stop this query  using much CPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to rebuild indices and update statistics for all databases from our SharePoint.